# How to recreate Northwind OrderLineItems type of form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've been creating a database and adding forms.
My current issue is making a user friendly form where there are multiple subrecords, like 1 order record showing many related orderDetail records.

The Northwind Database has a nice example of this.

OrderLineItems is a simple form that fits into OrderDetail.

I opened a second version of Access, and tried to create a form that mimics OrderLineItems. I can't do it. I noticed two things.

1. In Northwind, many forms have a blue dot on the icon. These can't be opened in Design View. Why? It makes it harder to see what is going on.
2. No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the selectable options to even remotely line up in terms of quantity between the OrderLineItem and my form. There are about 29 (under ALL) in Northwind and WAY too many to count on mine. I'm trying to figure out what the magic selection is to make them match, but can't find it.

What's the best way to make a form setup like Northwind's OrderDetail with OrderLineItems?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Northwind are you looking at? Web Database or Desktop? 2010, 2007 or something else?

Comment: TS101114818 is the file name. Is there another place to find a version? This is for Access 2010

Comment: OK, that's probably the Desktop 2007 version you can download from here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/results.aspx?ck=1&ex=2&qu=Northwind&av=all

Comment: That's the one I have, desktop 2007. Redownloaded just to check, no change. Also confused as to why the form (orderLineIte,s) shows all records but still has the record arrows at the bottom. Guess this must be a datasheet view or a tabular view?

Comment: I don't see the blue dot you're talking about. I can open every form in design view. Yes, they are using a Datasheet Subform for the Order Details. I'm not really sure what you are talking about in Question #2. Quantity of selectable options? Do you mean in the dropdown combobox?

Comment: Wish I could add screenshots, will try to figure out a way to do this. Am I allowed to link to imgur?

Comment: @HK1 Here's a link to imgur with the blue dots. Notice that not all forms have them. Only the ones that do can't be opened in design view. This seems to be a know problem, when searching for it I found tons of people listing this problem, but never a solution. [link] (http://imgur.com/jpO7bIe) In terms of the 'selectable options', I meant all of the stuff on the property sheet. I thought I'd make them line up by setting the options as the same, but this is impossible due to the sheer disparity in the number of properties available for setting.

Comment: Some guy named Xenou made a version of Northwind available for download. You'll find a link at this forum: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/687590-northwind-database-design-view.html There's also an explanation given there. You've downloaded the Web Application version of it and those forms cannot be put into design view, only layout view. I specifically mentioned the "desktop" version above. Make sure you download the Desktop version and you won't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought since I was running it inside of access that I was using a desktop version. Silly mistake.